# fecthing sanity data with next js and reach them , coming empty array,

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

ı am trying making blog site for me. ı set up nextjs with sanity cli and select blog schema.whenever ı try reach my data on sanity, arrays comes blanks when ı console data ,why? but ı have a couple catogry post like that.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export default function Home({document,arra}) {
  return (
    <div>
      sampple
      {console.log(document,arra)}
    </div>
  );
}

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "c3sj114g",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2022-10-02",
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN,
});

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "document"]`;
  const document = await client.fetch(query);

  const arque = `*[_type == "array"]`;
  const arra = await client.fetch(arque);
  return {
    props: { document,arra},
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here the `_type` you are passing in the `GROQ` query is incorrect. The `_type` should be the the name of the `schema`, of type document.

So, if the name of your schema of type `document` is `ingredient`, then you should  write the query like below:

```
const query = `*[_type == "ingredient"]`;
```